# "Login failed for user ''."

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have a WCF service, I added a database, I'm using EF, but when I try to connect to the database I have this problem...

```
public Producenci GetProducent(int id)
{
    dbMagazynierEntities context = new dbMagazynierEntities();
    context.Database.Connection.Open();

    var producent_entity = (from p in context.Producenci
                            where p.ID == id
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();

    context.Dispose();

    if (producent_entity != null)
    {
       return TranslateProducentEntity2Producent(producent_entity);
    }
    else
    {
       throw new Exception("error");
    }
}
```

I get

> Login failed for user '.'

this is my CS

```
<connectionStrings><add name="dbMagazynierEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MagazynierEntity.csdl|res://*/MagazynierEntity.ssdl|res://*/MagazynierEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PIOTR-TOSH\Piotr;initial catalog=dbMagazynier;integrated security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string has

```
integrated security=false;
```

So in that fashion you should specify the **user id** and **password** in the connection string.

Comment: when i changed it to integrated security=true;it worked, but i have question, is this a good practice? Or it should be fixed to false and i have to specify user id and password?

Comment: As with most things engineering, it always depends on the application. I would argue most of the time it's good practice to use integrated security=true; You don't want to expose sensitive information (user and password) so obviously as in a connection string like that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential(v=vs.110).aspx will give you more assistance on this topic.

Comment: if any one need a soltuion for this, i've made new Model.emdx and autheticated with userid and password, which i created in SQL Managment Studio... anyway thx Chris :)